# Create blocking popup in Blender api

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on

I'm writing an addon to import game models into Blender. But sometimes, there is a mismatch between a bone's name from the animation file and the name from the object file.

So I'd like, when the script encounters an unknown bone, to open a popup with a list of existing bones (plus an option to ignore the bone), that would pause the script until the user has chosen his result, and to get back the chosen option.

I've seen 
[How to call invoke_popup?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6512/how-to-call-invoke-popup)
to create a popup, but I'm stuck on several points :

- how to call it from my python code
- how to change its name (label) before calling it (to say for example "bone X not found")
- how to get the result of the selection
- how to get the user see and interact with the popup before the end of the script

Comment: `invoke_popup()` is not really reliable for your use case. You should better use a regular panel, because the user can't dismiss it like a popup (they are not really blocking in Blender).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I never used panels in scripting. Do you have a link to a tutorial to create this kind of panel?

Comment: Here are 3 resources: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Panels_and_Operators/Ping_Pong http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:2.5/Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_71_release/bpy.types.Panel.html#basic-panel-example

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Python can make a popup menu.

The options are either...

- Create a popup *on the fly*. using `bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu`
  http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.types.WindowManager.html#bpy.types.WindowManager.popup_menu
- Define a menu subclass of `bpy.types.Menu`, then call it. see:
  http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_release/bpy.types.Menu.html

Both of the links above include examples.

---

Regarding *"How to get the result of the selection"*, The way Blender works, menu items reference operators. So you would need to define an operator which is referenced from the menu.