# How to popup simple message box from python console?

Tags: python

How can i popup message box from python console ? something like message('test').

Comment: `bpy.ops.wm.splash('INVOKE_DEFAULT')` pops up the splash screen. On writing an operator with a dialogue [see Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6512/how-to-call-invoke-popup)

Comment: there is no popup box in blender like you get with javascript `alert("test")`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One way to do this is by using a operator and the self.report() method. Here is a example

```
import bpy

class MessageBoxOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "ui.show_message_box"
    bl_label = "Minimal Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        #this is where I send the message
        self.report({'INFO'}, "This is a test")
        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(MessageBoxOperator)

# test call to the 
bpy.ops.ui.show_message_box()
```

This will show a little message box up in the top tool bar and really isn't efficient for a bigger/longer message.

Another more efficient way of displaying a message box is window_manager.popup_menu() here is an example script:

```
import bpy

def ShowMessageBox(message = "", title = "Message Box", icon = 'INFO'):

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text=message)

    bpy.context.window_manager.popup_menu(draw, title = title, icon = icon)


#Shows a message box with a specific message 
ShowMessageBox("This is a message") 

#Shows a message box with a message and custom title
ShowMessageBox("This is a message", "This is a custom title")

#Shows a message box with a message, custom title, and a specific icon
ShowMessageBox("This is a message", "This is a custom title", 'ERROR')
```

You can see hear I made a custom message box method called ShowMessageBox() this is what the method will show starting from the first example to the third:

[image: ShowMessageBox() example 1]

[image: ShowMessageBox() example 2]

[image: ShowMessageBox() example 3]

Hope this helps! (sorry for the super late reply)

EDIT for 2.80

`UILayout.label(text="")` requires `text` to be a keyword argument.

```
self.layout.label(text=message)
```

Comment: The second method works but the first one , i can see any message box. where is it ? at top toolbar i can't see any message.

Comment: How do I make this work under 2.8?

Comment: @yaruncan I made it work by changing `self.layout.label(message)` to `self.layout.label(text=message)`