# How to popup simple message box in 2.8 or 2.9?

Tags: python

I just want to pop a 'hellow world' in a simple message box. Is there a builtin function to use now?

From an old post ([How to popup simple message box from python console?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109711/how-to-popup-simple-message-box-from-python-console)), i have to create lines of coding to make a custom popup window class.

For example in nuke. i simply type :

```
nuke.message("test")
nuke.ask('test')
```

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109711/how-to-popup-simple-message-box-from-python-console

Comment: yes , that's 2 years old and you need to write custom function. i'm curious if there's new faster method. Maybe there's a new builtin function , maybe like bpy.ops.message() without have to write custom function.

Comment: There is still no newer faster method, even in the just released 3.0.