# How to rename an image with a user interface blender python

Tags: python, add-on

i would like to create an add-on in python that can check the name of textures and if a texture is not well named, the add-on propose to rename it.
For that i would like to make a UI instead of `input("rename")`
I try to make a dialog box, but i didn't succed.

```
def createBadTextureList():
    badTextureList = []
    goodTexture = re.compile(r"^[DNR]_.*")
    modele = re.compile(r"^modele_.*")
    for image in bpy.data.images:
        if not(image.name == "Render Result" or image.name == "Viewer Node" or modele.match(image.name)):
            if not(goodTexture.match(image.name)):
                badTextureList.append(image)
    return badTextureList


class TextureName(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname="object.texture_name"
    bl_label="Vérifier le nom des textures"
    bl_description="Verifier que les textures respecte la nommenclature suivante : 'D_' ou 'N_' ou 'R_'"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True
    
    def execute(self, context):
        badTextureList = createBadTextureList()
        for texture in badTextureList:
            print("la texture " + texture.name + " est mal nommée")
            newName = input("renommer")
            texture.name = newName
        return {"FINISHED"}

class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Export"
    bl_idname = "VIEW_3D_PT_Export"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "SNCF"       
                    
    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text = "Nomenclature :")
        self.layout.label(text = "- Modèle : 'modele_...'")
        self.layout.label(text = "- Texture : ")
        self.layout.label(text = "    Diffuse : 'D_...'" )
        self.layout.label(text = "    Normal = 'N_...'" )
        self.layout.label(text = "    Rougthness = 'R_...'" )
        self.layout.column().operator(TextureName.bl_idname)


classes = [MyPanel, TextureName]

def register():    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Does anybody have an idea ?
Thanks

Comment: is this helpful? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/109711/how-to-popup-simple-message-box-from-python-console

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately no. The problem with a simple UI is that i can't ask to an user to enter text in a loop. I have to create a bpy.props for every texture i want to rename. But the way props are created doesn't work with a loop.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a UIList then?